# if/else list on possible date conditions never succeeds

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

I have JavaScript code like the following, and could not get an `alert` message. Probably the if/else loop does not work. How can I fix this?

```js
document.getElementById('mydate').onchange = function() {
  var selectedDateFromCalendar = this.value;

  var currentdate = new Date();

  var Diff = new Date(selectedDateFromCalendar) - currentdate;

  var diffDays = Math.ceil(Diff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));

  if ((selectedDateFromCalendar) - currentdate < 0) {
    alert("out of date");
  } else if ((selectedDateFromCalendar) - currentdate == 0) {
    alert("last day of the event");
  } else if ((selectedDateFromCalendar) - currentdate >= 1) {
    alert("last " + diffDays + " day");
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="date" id="mydate">
```

Comment: Which date-picker are you using?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_date i think this one

Comment: Problem 1: a typo. `myDate` (the id) is not the same as `mydate` (which you're trying to select). Problem 2: You're trying to subtract a `Date` object (`currentdate`) from a string (`selectedDateFromCalendar`). The result is `NaN` (not a number), which fails all of your comparisons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working, the problem was you were selection wrong id `mydate` instead of `myDate` and the second one was you were subtracting string with date which were making your calculation wrong as also mention in comment by @Paul.

```js
document.getElementById('myDate').onchange = function () {//changed 
    var selectedDateFromCalendar = new Date(this.value);  //changed

    var currentdate = new Date();

    var Diff = new Date(selectedDateFromCalendar) - currentdate;

    var diffDays = Math.ceil(Diff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));

    if ((selectedDateFromCalendar) - currentdate < 0) {
        alert("out of date");
    }
    else if ((selectedDateFromCalendar) - currentdate == 0) {
        alert("last day of the event");
    }
    else if ((selectedDateFromCalendar) - currentdate >= 1) {
        alert("last " + diffDays + " day");
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="date" id="myDate">
```

Answer (score 1):

This works

```
window.onload = function()
{
    document.getElementById('myDate').onchange = function () {
        var selectedDateFromCalendar = new Date(this.value);

        var currentdate = new Date();

        var Diff = new Date(selectedDateFromCalendar) - currentdate;

        var diffDays = Math.ceil(Diff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));

        if ((selectedDateFromCalendar) - currentdate < 0) {
            alert("out of date");
        }
        else if ((selectedDateFromCalendar) - currentdate == 0) {
            alert("last day of the event");
        }
        else if ((selectedDateFromCalendar) - currentdate >= 1) {
            alert("last " + diffDays + " day");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This may work........

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
       <title>Page Title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="date" id="myDate">
   <script>
      document.getElementById('mydate').onchange = function () {
      var selectedDateFromCalendar = this.value;

      var currentdate = new Date();

      var Diff = new Date(selectedDateFromCalendar) - currentdate;

      var diffDays = Math.ceil(Diff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));

      if (new Date(selectedDateFromCalendar) - currentdate < 0) {
          alert("out of date");
      }
      else if (new Date(selectedDateFromCalendar) - currentdate == 0) {
        alert("last day of the event");
      }
      else if (new Date(selectedDateFromCalendar) - currentdate >= 1) {
        alert("last " + diffDays + " day");
      }
  }
</script>
</body>  
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have already some good answers. Let me add something new:

1. Your "input" tag is not closed. Close it:

   `<input type="date" id="myDate" />`
2. You reference the input through its "id", but you don't write its "id" properly. You should write:
   `document.getElementById('myDate')`

   - Notice the capital letter.
3. How is the user supposed to provide the date in the input? I've made this code in which the user uses backslashes to separate years, months and days, so you can build your "selectedDateFromCalendar" object nicely:

   ```
   var auxlist = this.value.split("/");
   var selectedDateFromCalendar = new Date(auxlist[0],auxlist[1],auxlist[2],0,0,0,0);
   ```

This works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

  <input type="date" id="myDate" />

  <script>
    document.getElementById('myDate').onchange = function () {
        var auxlist = this.value.split("/");
        var selectedDateFromCalendar = new Date(auxlist[0],auxlist[1],auxlist[2],0,0,0,0);

        var currentdate = new Date();

        var Diff = new Date(selectedDateFromCalendar) - currentdate;

        var diffDays = Math.ceil(Diff / (1000 * 3600 * 24));

        console.log(selectedDateFromCalendar);

        if ((selectedDateFromCalendar) - currentdate < 0) {
            alert("out of date");
        }
        else if ((selectedDateFromCalendar) - currentdate == 0) {
            alert("last day of the event");
        }
        else if ((selectedDateFromCalendar) - currentdate >= 1) {
            alert("last " + diffDays + " day");
        }
    }
</script>
</body>  
</html>
```

`